# debugging my asp.net website has some unknown text in url

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, url, localhost

In my asp.net Website project , I run `/Functions/Profile/Pages/MySetting.aspx` .
My code works perfectly but the url become
`http://localhost:51479/%28S%28xfqh4f0sufiuznzp1cyxir5s%29%29/Functions/Profile/Pages/MySetting.aspx`
 instead of
`http://localhost:51479/Functions/Profile/Pages/MySetting.aspx` .
What wrong in my project ?
Thanks !

Comment: Have you set up the site to use cookieless sessions?

Comment: Where can I set-up this ? Can you show me some ?

Comment: In your web.config, what does the `sessionState` element look like?

Comment: Check this link how it gets configured. http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/implementing_cookieless_session_aspnet.aspx

Comment: @DavidG ,  `<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true" timeout="3000"></sessionState>`

Comment: Thanks guys , when I set sessionState's cookieless to `False` , everything is OK !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `cookieless` sessions. Change this line in your web.config:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true" timeout="3000"></sessionState>
```

to this:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="3000"></sessionState>
```